# Jupyter Notebook Python won't show graphs for output

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter Notebook to learn Python (Python 3) and I started to explore data visualization in Jupyter. But everytime I tried to run the code for graphs it appears that the kernel keeps loading forever and will not produce any output at all. 
Here's one of my codes below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df= pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
print(df.head())

num_bins = 10
plt.hist(df['age'], num_bins, density=1, facecolor='red', alpha =0.5)
plt.show()
```

Is there something that I miss here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tag matplotlib as well.

Comment: How big is your CSV file? Also, are you sure you have set the path of the CSV file correctly? Testing on my own system with an example data frame, this code works fine.

Comment: I would suggest you split your code into multiple cells. Imports in once cell loading data in one cell and plotting the graph in another cell. Wil make it easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

and then in the last, you don't need to add `plt.show()` any more.
I hope this can help you.